# Which one is correct "Please close the door. I am in a draught" or "I am in draughts"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

This is very confusing. "Wind" can countable or uncountable, but "Draught" is only a countable noun.

So, when I am sitting in my house, probably there are many draughts or many flows of cool air striking me.

But why does the dictionary say "**Can you close the window? I’m in a draught.**"?

I would think "**Can you close the window? I’m in draughts.**" makes more sense.

Which one is correct "**Please close the door. I am in a draught**" or "**I am in draughts**"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/draught) defines a draught as "a current of unpleasantly cold air blowing through a room", so you can only really have one draught in a room. The correct way of saying it would be:

> Please close the door: I am in a draught.

As this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&content=letting%20in%20a%20draught%2C%20there%20is%20a%20draught%2C%20I%20am%20in%20a%20draught&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cletting%20in%20a%20draught%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20is%20a%20draught%3B%2Cc0) shows, you would generally say

> Please close the door: there is a draught.
> Please close the door: it's letting in a draught.

Note that, if you did want to use the plural, you would need a determiner, for example "I am in some draughts". This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&content=a%20draught%2C%20some%20draughts&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20draught%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20draughts%3B%2Cc0) shows that the plural is very uncommon, and none of the actual instances relate to the "cold air" meaning.